# how to convert character type time to int?

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing time as a character type in the following manner.

```
time=c("5 mins 30 seconds","1 min 46 seconds","6 mins 40 seconds","20 seconds","2 seconds")
student=c("A","B","C")
df<-data.frame(student,time)
```

**I want to sort time taken by them and then plot. How should I proceed?

*Also how to convert time to INT type in seconds?***

Comment: Will the format be consistent, if yes then we can do it by parsing the string.

Answer (score 1):

If the format remains same then, we can use strptime function in R

```
time<- c("5 mins 30 seconds","3 mins 46 seconds","6 mins 40 seconds")
times <- strptime(time, "%M mins %S seconds")
times <- format(times, "%H:%M:%S")
student=c("A","B","C")
df<-data.frame(student,times)
```

Comment: what if the field given is as such given above- a mixture. How to deal then?

Comment: You would have to parse the timestamps.

Comment: `parse_date_time` in R might be useful.

Comment: Can you please explain it in a bit more detail?